# Triggering animation via setState not working

Tags: reactjs, react-animated, react-devtools

I am calling a function when I hit a waypoint in my page. The function logs the state after calling setState, which shows that the state has been updated to `{visible: true}` however, in React Dev Tools, it shows that the state is still false. Because the state is still false, the Animated component isn't visible. If I change `visible` to true using React Dev Tools, the Animated component becomes visible.

I think my problem is because my setState isn't updating the component state outside of the function call, this would explain why logging the component's state shows as updated in console but not triggering a rerender nor making the `Animated` component's isVisible property set to true via the state attribute.

This is the component I am working on

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { Waypoint } from  'react-waypoint'
import { Animated } from 'react-animated-css'

export default class About extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false,
    };

    this.OnEnter = this.onEnter.bind(this);
  }


  onEnter({ currentPosition }){
        this.setState({
            visible: true
        });
        console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() { 
    return (
            <Waypoint onEnter={this.onEnter}></Waypoint>
            <Animated animationIn="fadeInUp" isVisible={this.state.visible}>
                <h2 className="mb-4">About Me</h2>
                <p>A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary nutrients.</p>
            </Animated>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that a typo in the constructor? `this.OnEnter = this.onEnter.bind(this);` instead of `this.onEnter = this.onEnter.bind(this);`? (Capital O)

Comment: Hmmm something's off with this. `setState` is asynchronous, so if you call it then `console.log` the state on the next line, it won't show the updated state. So the fact that your logging apparently _does_ show the state has changed doesn't really make sense. Try adding the `console.log` to the `setState` callback and see if the state value is updated there (see this article for more details: https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296)

Comment: @Jayce444 that is interesting that it is showing the correct state, I'll look into the callback though for future debugging

Comment: @HariharDas that was the issue! Thank you so much. Feel free to post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting my comment as the answer*.

There is a typo error.

Please update the line `this.OnEnter = this.onEnter.bind(this);` to `this.onEnter = this.onEnter.bind(this);`.